# How do I send message to ActorRef at start of Akka-Stream 2.0 flow?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

The goal is to send the `WSConnectEvent` once a client is connected and the stream starts. With akka-streams 1.0 I was able to accomplish this with the following:

```
Flow(Source.actorRef[WSResponseEvent](65535, OverflowStrategy.fail)) {
  implicit builder =>
    sdpSource =>

      // Incoming SDP offer flow
      val fromWebsocket = builder.add(Flow[Message].collect {
        case TextMessage.Strict(txt) => {
          val event = txt.parseJson.convertTo[WSResponseEvent]
          WSMessageEvent(callUUID, userUUID, event.id, event.data)
        }
      })

      // Outgoing SDP answer flow
      val toWebsocket = builder.add(Flow[WSResponseEvent].map {
        case msg: WSResponseEvent => TextMessage(msg.toJson.compactPrint)
      })

      val callActorSelection = actorSystem.actorSelection(s"/user/application/call-service/call-${callUUID.toString}")
      val callActorRef = Await.result(callActorSelection.resolveOne(), Duration.Inf);
      val callActorSink = Sink.actorRef[CallControlEvent](callActorRef, WSDisconnectEvent(callUUID, userUUID))

      // Join events, also sends actor for sending stuff
      val merge = builder.add(Merge[CallControlEvent](2))
      val actorAsSource = builder.materializedValue.map(actor => WSConnectEvent(callUUID, userUUID, actor))

      fromWebsocket ~> merge.in(0)
      actorAsSource ~> merge.in(1)

      merge ~> callActorSink
      sdpSource ~> toWebsocket
      (fromWebsocket.inlet, toWebsocket.outlet)
}
```

In trying to upgrade this to work with Akka-Streams 2.0.1 I changed to the following code, but I am no loner receiving the `WSConnectEvent` message. I'm not sure if this is because my source is setup incorrectly, or I am not materializing the `ActorRef` properly.

```
val sdpSource = Source.actorRef[WSResponseEvent](65535, OverflowStrategy.fail)

Flow.fromGraph(
  GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>

    // Incoming SDP offer flow
    val fromWebsocket = builder.add(Flow[Message].collect {
      case TextMessage.Strict(txt) => {
        val event = txt.parseJson.convertTo[WSResponseEvent]
        WSMessageEvent(callUUID, userUUID, event.id, event.data)
      }
    })

    // Outgoing SDP answer flow
    val toWebsocket = builder.add(Flow[WSResponseEvent].map {
      case msg: WSResponseEvent => TextMessage(msg.toJson.compactPrint)
    })

    val callActorSelection = actorSystem.actorSelection(s"/user/application/call-service/call-${callUUID.toString}")
    val callActorRef = Await.result(callActorSelection.resolveOne(), Duration.Inf);
    val callActorSink = Sink.actorRef[CallControlEvent](callActorRef, WSDisconnectEvent(callUUID, userUUID))

    // Join events, also sends actor for sending stuff
    val merge = builder.add(Merge[CallControlEvent](2))
    val actorAsSource = sdpSource.mapMaterializedValue(WSConnectEvent(callUUID, userUUID, _))

    fromWebsocket ~> merge.in(0)
    actorAsSource ~> merge.in(1)

    merge ~> callActorSink
    sdpSource ~> toWebsocket
    FlowShape(fromWebsocket.in, toWebsocket.out)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of johanandren, `mapMaterializedValue` was not the correct approach, instead I needed to construct a flow to send the `WSConnectEvent` and connect the output of `builder.materializeValue` through it through to the 'merge' in port, like so:

```
// Join events, also sends actor for sending stuff
val actorConnected = Flow[ActorRef].map(WSConnectEvent(callUUID, userUUID, _))

builder.materializedValue ~> actorConnected ~> merge.in(1)
```

The full working example:

```
val sdpSource: Source[WSResponseEvent, ActorRef] = Source.actorRef[WSResponseEvent](65535, OverflowStrategy.fail)

Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sdpSource) {
  implicit builder =>
    { (responseSource) =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      // Incoming SDP offer flow
      val fromWebsocket = builder.add(Flow[Message].mapAsync(1)(_ match {
        case tm: TextMessage => tm.textStream.runFold("")(_ + _).map(Some(_))
        case bm: BinaryMessage =>
          bm.dataStream.runWith(Sink.ignore)
          Future.successful(None)
      }).collect {
        case Some(txt) => {
          val event = txt.parseJson.convertTo[WSResponseEvent]
          WSMessageEvent(callUUID, userUUID, event.id, event.data)
        }
      })

      // Outgoing SDP answer flow
      val toWebsocket = builder.add(Flow[WSResponseEvent].map {
        case msg: WSResponseEvent => TextMessage(msg.toJson.compactPrint)
      })

      val callActorSelection = actorSystem.actorSelection(s"/user/application/call-service/call-${callUUID.toString}")
      val callActorRef = Await.result(callActorSelection.resolveOne(), 2.minutes);
      val toCallActor = builder.add(Sink.actorRef[CallControlEvent](callActorRef, WSDisconnectEvent(callUUID, userUUID)))

      // Join events, also sends actor for sending stuff
      val merge = builder.add(Merge[CallControlEvent](2))
      val actorConnected = Flow[ActorRef].map(WSConnectEvent(callUUID, userUUID, _))

      fromWebsocket ~> merge.in(0)
      builder.materializedValue ~> actorConnected ~> merge.in(1)

      merge ~> toCallActor
      responseSource ~> toWebsocket

      FlowShape.of(fromWebsocket.in, toWebsocket.out)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `sdpSource.mapMaterializedValue(...)` only transforms the materialized value from one type (`ActorRef` to `WSConnectEvent`), it does not in any way emit it as an element from the `Source`.

`Source.materializedValue` however, provides a source that will emit the materialized value once the graph is materialized.

So, what you want to do is:

```
fromWebsocket                   ~> merge.in(0)
actorAsSource.materializedValue ~> merge.in(1)
```

Comment: I think you might be referring to builder.materializedValue, as Source does not expose this property (at least not with akka-streams 2.0.1).

After a bit more research, I am not sure it is possible to construct a Source from a Source.actorRef such that it can emit the first message.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I was unclear, it is available from the builder, (it is also a method on an instance of Source, which is why I referred to it like that).

Comment: You can see an example that does something like what you are trying to do that might be helpful here: https://github.com/johanandren/scala-stockholm-cluster-message-broker/blob/master/src/main/scala/WebServer.scala#L82

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to come back to this, but your example helped me figure out my missing pieces.. thanks. I'll post the correct answer.